# SQL Server stored procedure Issue

Tags: sql, sql-server

In my query I have 3 tables `GoodsReceivedNote`, `GoodsReceivedNoteDetail` and `TransferNote`. In `GoodsReceivedNoteDetails` I am receiving the products and in transfer note I am transferring product.

For example: I am receiving a product name salt on 10-2-2015   50 kg  and I am transferring the product to another location on 10-2-2015 10kg  and 12-2-2015 25 kg. And I am receiving product name Salt on 1-3-15 100 kg. And transfer the product to another location on 5-3-2015 50 kg. Now I want to sum the total transfer quantity of particular grn id (ie) in first grn between (10-2-2015 -31-2-2015).

`GoodsReceivedNote`:

```
GoodsReceivedNoteID | LocationID
     1              |      1
     2              |      1
```

`GoodsReceivedNoteDetail`:

```
GoodsReceivedNoteDetailID|GoodsReceivedNoteID|AcceptedQuantity|ProductID|CreatedON|
    1                     | 1                | 50 |  1  |10-2-2015
    2                     | 2                | 100|  1  |1-3-2015
```

`TransferNote`:

```
Fromlocation |Tolocation|ProductID|TransferQuantity|CreatedOn|
 1              2             1       10|10-2-2015
 1              2             1       25 |12-2-2015
 1              2             1       50 |5-3-2015``
```

My expected result:

```
GoodsReceivedNoteID
```

`|LocationID|AcceptedQuantity|ProductID|CreatedOn|Fromlocation |Tolocation|ProductID|TransferQuantity
1  | 1   | 50   |   1 |  10-2-2015   |   1   |   2  |   1  |  35  |
2  | 2   | 100  | 1   |    1-3-15    |   1   |   2  |   1  |  50  |`

Query:

```
SELECT DISTINCT
    [GRN].[GoodsReceivedNoteNo] ,
    [GRN].[LocationID] ,
    [GRN].[CreatedOn] ,
    [POD].[UnitPrice] AS [BasicRate] ,
    [POD].[VAT] ,
    [POD].[UnitPrice] * [GRND].[ReceivedQuantity] AS [CostofPurchase] ,
    [PO].[PurchaseOrderNo] ,
    [V].[VendorName] ,
    [GRN].[SupplierInvoiceNo] ,
    [GRN].[SupplierInvoiceDate] ,
    [SR].[LRNO] ,
    [T].[TransporterName] ,
    SUBSTRING([LPM].[BarCode], 4, 4) [Code] ,
    RIGHT([LPM].[BarCode], 6) [ProductCode] ,
    [P].[ProductName] ,
    [UT].[UnitTypeShortCode] ,
    CAST([GRND].[ReceivedQuantity] AS DECIMAL(18, 2)) AS [ReceivedQuantity] ,
    CAST([GRND].[RejectedQuantity] AS DECIMAL(18, 2)) AS [RejectedQuantity] ,
    CAST([GRND].[AcceptedQuantity] AS DECIMAL(18, 2)) AS [AcceptedQuantity] ,
    CAST([GRND].[UnitPrice] AS DECIMAL(18, 2)) AS [BasicRate] ,
    CAST(ISNULL(( [GRND].[UnitPrice] * [GRND].[ReceivedQuantity] ), 0.00) AS DECIMAL(18, 2)) [BasicValue] ,
    [GRND].[VAT] ,
    CASE WHEN COUNT([GRND].[GoodsReceivedNoteID]) OVER ( PARTITION BY [GRND].[GoodsReceivedNoteID] ) > 1
         THEN ISNULL(( [GRND].[FreightCharges] ), 0.00)
         ELSE ISNULL(( [OEC].[FreightCharges] ), 0.00)
    END [FreightApportioned] ,
    CASE WHEN COUNT([GRND].[GoodsReceivedNoteID]) OVER ( PARTITION BY [GRND].[GoodsReceivedNoteID] ) > 1
         THEN ISNULL(( [GRND].[LoadingCost] + [GRND].[UnloadingCost] ), 0.00)
         ELSE ISNULL(( [OEC].[LoadingCost] + [OEC].[UnloadingCost] ), 0.00)
    END [LoadingandUnloadingApportioned] ,
    CASE WHEN COUNT([GRND].[GoodsReceivedNoteID]) OVER ( PARTITION BY [GRND].[GoodsReceivedNoteID] ) > 1
         THEN ISNULL(( [GRND].[FreightCharges] ), 0.00) + ISNULL(( [GRND].[LoadingCost] + [GRND].[UnloadingCost] ), 0.00)
              + ISNULL(( [GRND].[UnitPrice] ), 0.00)
         ELSE ISNULL(( [OEC].[FreightCharges] ), 0.00) + ISNULL(( [OEC].[LoadingCost] + [OEC].[UnloadingCost] ), 0.00)
              + ISNULL(( [GRND].[UnitPrice] ), 0.00)
    END [TotalCost] ,
    [TN].[CreatedOn] ,
    [TN].[TransferQuantity] ,
    [TN].[Tolocation] ,
    [TN].[ProductID] ,
    [GRND].[ProductID] ,
    ( [TN].[TransferQuantity] * [TN].[UnitPrice] ) AS [VALUE] ,
    [L].[Location] ,
    [TN].[FreightCharge] ,
    ( [TN].[LoadingCharge] + [TN].[UnLoadingCharge] ) AS [LoadingandUnloadingCharges] ,
    ( [TN].[FreightCharge] + [TN].[LoadingCharge] + [TN].[UnLoadingCharge] ) AS [LoadingCost]
FROM    
    [GoodsReceivedNoteDetail] [GRND]
LEFT OUTER JOIN 
    [GoodsReceivedNote] [GRN] ON [GRN].[GoodsReceivedNoteID] = [GRND].[GoodsReceivedNoteID]
LEFT OUTER JOIN 
    [PurchaseOrder] [PO] ON [PO].[PurchaseOrderID] = [GRN].[PurchaseOrderID]
LEFT OUTER JOIN 
    [Vendor] [V] ON [V].[VendorID] = [PO].[VendorID]
LEFT OUTER JOIN 
    [SecurityRegister] [SR] ON [SR].[SecurityRegisterID] = [GRN].[SecurityRegisterID]
LEFT OUTER JOIN 
    [Transporter] [T] ON [T].[TransporterID] = [SR].[TransporterID]
LEFT OUTER JOIN 
    [OtherExpenseCost] [OEC] ON [OEC].[GoodsReceivedNoteID] = [GRN].[GoodsReceivedNoteID]
LEFT OUTER JOIN 
    [Product] [P] ON [P].[ProductID] = [GRND].[ProductID]
LEFT OUTER JOIN 
    [LocationProductMap] [LPM] ON [LPM].[ProductID] = [GRND].[ProductID]
LEFT OUTER JOIN 
    [UnitType] [UT] ON [UT].[UnitTypeID] = [P].[UnitTypeID]
LEFT OUTER JOIN 
    [PurchaseOrderDetail] [POD] ON [POD].[PurchaseOrderID] = [PO].[PurchaseOrderID]
LEFT OUTER JOIN 
    [TransferNote] [TN] ON [TN].[ProductID] = [GRND].[ProductID]
LEFT OUTER JOIN 
    [Locations] [L] ON [L].[LocationID] = [TN].[Tolocation]
WHERE   
    (@d_StartDate = ''
      OR CAST([GRND].[CreatedOn] AS DATE) >= @d_StartDate
      OR CAST([GRND].[CreatedOn] AS DATE) = @d_StartDate)
    AND (@d_EndDate = ''
          OR CAST([GRND].[CreatedOn] AS DATE) <= @d_EndDate)
    AND (@i_GrnStartNo = '0'
          OR [GRN].[GoodsReceivedNoteNo] >= @i_GrnStartNo)
    AND (@i_GrnEndNo = '0'
          OR [GRN].[GoodsReceivedNoteNo] <= @i_GrnEndNo)
    AND ([GRN].[LocationID] = @i_LocationID)  
    --AND CAST( GRND.CreatedOn AS DATE)=@d_StartDate
```

Comment: Please read FAQ how to ask question (http://stackoverflow.com/help/asking), what have u done so far? What is the problem?

Comment: @Rocketq  i want to sum the  tranfer qty based on grn date of particular grn

Answer (score 0):

Not totally clear on this.

```
(@d_StartDate = ''
  OR CAST([GRND].[CreatedOn] AS DATE) >= @d_StartDate
  OR CAST([GRND].[CreatedOn] AS DATE) = @d_StartDate)
```

The third part is a duplicate - will be captured by the condition above it.

In regards to "i want to sum the tranfer qty based on grn date of particular grn" please clarify. You have date criteria within your WHERE clause already, and no sign of any SUM at the top, so I'm not clear what you want changing and where.

```
SUM([TN].[TransferQuantity]) OVER (PARTITION BY GRN.LocationID)
```

in your select statement for example would leave your date selection criteria as they are but give you a subtotal for that location. Whereas something like

```
SUM(CASE WHEN CAST( GRND.CreatedOn AS DATE)=@d_StartDate THEN [TN].[TransferQuantity] ELSE 0 END) OVER (PARTITION BY GRN.LocationID)
```

would give you the subtotal for that location id only where the date was the one supplied.